# Typescript - addEventListener type interface for scroll event

Tags: typescript, dom, dom-events, type-inference

What is the correct way to add type interface when listening to scroll event.

```js
    onMounted(() => {
      ...
      // Call when mounted;
    
      document.addEventListener("scroll", (e: ScrollEvent) => {
        console.log(e); // Type interface of ScrollEvent
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is an example, and here's the MDN page for [`Document: scroll event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event).

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9nATgEwM5QLxQN4FgBQUUAHgFxQB2ArgLYBGEiA3AUSOdfYy-gL48EAZlQoBjYAEs4FKAHMIwAMqjEcADZr4SZBIoBDYBHQAKAJTktKdHkJRECqohk2iRMlADuu5HA8A6VBV1NQANABpWV3ZPb18AoI0ATQjbfgJeAiERcSkZD0QJQ2VVDUsdfUMTCDUIGggKYHgGvV1GcgAJABUAWQAZAFEauoawqFEEKwsJtHMoADc4CWQcSOra+sbpYBaKRj9DYk2GjcwoAClFAHkAOQDgAopZCUEQY3HtVFHqDVGAJlMeBl8FkxJJpFAABZ6CjIGrFYJQYwQOYbcj9FENWYLJYrWwAejxriJxJJUAAehTKVSKZECVBOhDoIESmooMiThJ0AArKioYBQaFQXR86GiaBwQRQYCMqB0PSoaDok6iNTy1CRfKFCDw0rTXQGIzGHyiWgbPzyYCDdYNABCIAAkshjAByd5WZ2mACEowtOs0eoqhtMAPSmXwXhhcT0yGQSoavU5hl2iBdzOCztGUJhcISahD+CAA)

```ts
type Coords = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};

function getScrollCoordinates (): Coords {
  return {
    x: window.scrollX,
    y: window.scrollY,
  };
}

function writeScrollCoordinates (elementContainer: HTMLElement, coords: Coords): void {
  elementContainer.textContent = JSON.stringify(coords, null, 2);
}

function handleScroll (event: Event): void {
  //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  // The scroll event is just an instance of the base Event class
  writeScrollCoordinates(document.getElementById('coords')!, getScrollCoordinates());
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

Example:

```js
"use strict";
function getScrollCoordinates() {
    return {
        x: window.scrollX,
        y: window.scrollY,
    };
}
function writeScrollCoordinates(elementContainer, coords) {
    elementContainer.textContent = JSON.stringify(coords, null, 2);
}
function handleScroll(event) {
    //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    // The scroll event is just an instance of the base Event class
    writeScrollCoordinates(document.getElementById('coords'), getScrollCoordinates());
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll);
```

```css
body {
  --size: 10000px;
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
}

#coords {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<pre><code id="coords">Scroll to see coordinates</code></pre>
```

Comment: I see, thanks. I was hoping to get like autocomplete suggestion specific for scroll event.

Comment: @Evan What information do you want in reaction to the user's scrolling? See my updated answer for how to get window coordinates.

Comment: yes, the updated answer is good enough for me. thanks